# Deleting Checked rows from gridview

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I'm trying to delete checked(Selected) rows from `gridview`, but selected row is not deleting. Why?

```
//Class-Method

public void DeleteDataRow(string ID)
{
    using (SqlCommand xComm = new SqlCommand())
    {
        Conn.Open();
        new SqlCommand("Delete from Costumers Where CID='" + ID + "' ", Conn);
        Conn.Close();
    }
}

//webform-Method

protected void xbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GV.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox C = row.Cells[0].FindControl("Check") as CheckBox;
        string  ID= row.Cells[1].Text;
        if(C.Checked)
        {
            m.DeleteDataRow(ID);
        }
    }

    GV.DataSource = m.Select();
    GV.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: put code dude, how are you selecting? check boxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are there any error messages? Also where are you defining `Conn`, and is it accessible to *DeleteDataRow()*?

If so, you'll need to define `xComm` a bit differently within your *using* statement.

After you open the connection, you need to execute the query in some matter such as using *ExecuteNonQuery* to fire the sql statement. See [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public void DeleteDataRow(string ID)
{
    using (SqlCommand xComm = new SqlCommand("Delete from Customers Where CID='" + ID + "' ", Conn))
    {
        Conn.Open();
        int result = xComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Another thing to note is that you may want to check the spelling of *Customers* in your query.